# speeding up data frame matching

Tags: performance, r

I have two dataframes, much like these:

```
data = data.frame(data=cbind(1:12,rep(c(1,2),6),rep(c(1,2,3),4)))
colnames(data)=c('v','h','c')

lookup = data.frame(data=cbind(c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3)),rep(c(1,2,3),2),21:26))
colnames(lookup)=c('h','c','t')
```

I want to subtract lookup$t from data$v where the h and c columns match.

I thought something like this would work

```
data$v-lookup$t[lookup$h==data$h&lookup$c==data$c]
```

but doesn't magically know that I want to implicitly iterate over the rows of data

I ended up doing this

```
myt = c()
for(i in 1:12) {
myt[i] = lookup$t[lookup$h==data$h[i]&lookup$c==data$c[i]]
}
```

which works fine, but I'm hoping someone can suggest a more sensible way that doesn't involve a loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you could merge and then do the math:

```
dataLookedUp <- merge(data, lookup)
dataLookedUp$newValue <- with(dataLookedUp, v - t )
```

For your real data, is the merge and calc faster?

If data and/or lookup is really big you might use data.table to create an index before the merge in order to speed it up.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative that is 1.) more familiar to those accustomed to SQL queries and 2.) often faster than the standard merge is to use the [sqldf](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/) package. (Note that on Mac OS X, you'll probably want to install Tcl/Tk, on which sqldf depends.) As an added bonus, sqldf converts strings to factors automagically by default.

```
install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)
data <- data.frame(v = 1:12, h = rep(c("one", "two"), 6), c = rep(c("one", "two", "three"), 4))
lookup <- data.frame(h = c(rep("one", 3), rep("two", 3)), c = rep(c("one", "two", "three"), 2), t =  21:26)
soln <- sqldf("select * from data inner join lookup using (h, c)")
soln <- transform(soln, v.minus.t = v - t)
```

Comment: Note that the last two lines could be combined like this: `sqldf("select *, v - t as 'v.minus.t' from data join lookup using (h, c)")`

Answer (score 4):

With your integer columns, I don't think there's anything you can do to improve on JD's offering, but if you had strings in the columns on which you merge, you could create factors with `as.factor`, which could speed up the `merge` depending on the size of your data set and how many merges/sorts you anticipate:

```
data <- data.frame(v = 1:12, h = rep(c("one", "two"), 6), c = rep(c("one", "two", "three"), 4))
lookup <- data.frame(h = c(rep("one", 3), rep("two", 3)), c = rep(c("one", "two", "three"), 2), t =  21:26)
data <- transform(data, h = as.factor(h), c = as.factor(c))
lookup <- transform(lookup, h = as.factor(h), c = as.factor(c))
temp <- merge(data, lookup)
temp <- transform(temp, v.minus.t = v - t)
```

Comment: in reality, they are all strings, because I am terrible at creating data frames. thanks!

Comment: @ansate -- FWIW, you can tinker with your `stringsAsFactors` option and the `read.table` options to make strings read in as factors by default. The default should be to read strings as factors.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect for `data.table` using *by without by*

```
library(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(data)
lookup <- as.data.table(lookup)
setkey(data, h, c)
setkey(lookup, h,c)

data[lookup, list(v,t, newValue = v-t)]
```